# Connect multiple databases dynamically in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, multiple-databases, connection

I'm building an application which requires connecting 2 database. first one is static and another one is dynamic.
config/database.php is like

```
'mysql' => 
array (
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'database' => 'blog',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'unix_socket' => '',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => NULL,
),
'business2' => 
array (
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'database' => 'blog2',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'unix_socket' => '',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => NULL,
),
```

and model code is like

```
Class  TableNewData extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'business3';
    protected $table = 'table2_data';
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->get()->toArray();
    }
}
```

I am able to connect multiple databases if I give static connection details but I am unable to connect database if I give dynamic connection details  like

```
 $connection = Session::get()->connection;
```

or

```
$connection=$_SESSION('connection');
```

What is the best way to connect multiple databases dynamically without effecting performance of application?

Comment: try `setConnection` method `$someModel->setConnection($connection);`

Comment: throwing error `Class App\Models\TableNewData does not exist`

Comment: don't you have `app\Models\TableNewData.php` class ? check class namespace

Comment: Yes I have the class and I am getting the above error only after placing `setConnection` method

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload` to for the class not existing exception.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Still getting same error

Comment: Is `TableNewData` namespaced correctly, with `namespace App\Models;`?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. I am getting this error only when `$someModel->setConnection($connection);` code in `TableNewData`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of changing the connection at runtime is to set the values via the config:

```
config(['database.connections.mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_database'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'my_user'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
]]);
```

This can be applied in a middleware to dynamically switch between tenant databases, for example.

You can also specify a connection via the DB facade:

```
DB::connection('mysql_2')->select(...);
```

Comment: Where I have to keep the code? In config/database.php or model or middleware? I have 100+ databases and everytime I have to connect 1 static database and another one is one in remaining 100 databases

Comment: You're saying each database has it's own unique connection credentials? If that's the case, I would store them in a database and do a lookup to find the necessary username/password. I've seen this approach done in large SAS applications with 1000s of customers, each with their own database.

Comment: Yes. primary database will have username/password and connection name. I am not storing credential details in database but keeping them in config/database.php file

Comment: Storing connection details in database or code is not my problem. I am facing issue with calling that data dynamically. If I give connection details statically it is working fine but I am unable to give connection details dynamically

Comment: That's what I'm showing with the `config(...)` in my answer. Every time a request comes in, use the config helper to set the connection details. This will set the values in the container and you won't need to call `setConnection` or anything else. This is just an example where `default` is `mysql` in `config/database.php`.

Comment: Did the same thing but it is still connecting to default connection instead of second connection

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you. This blog can definitely help you out.

[The Ultimate Guide for Laravel Multi Tenant with Multi Database](https://hackernoon.com/the-ultimate-guide-for-laravel-multi-tenant-with-multi-database-779ea4592783)

Here is how the config/database.php file looks like based on your situation. Since the second one is dynamic, there is no need to define the database.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'blog'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
'business' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => '',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

Basically, set up a database helper function which connects to the database at runtime and then calls it in the right middleware.I just put the helper file at database/utilities/helpers.php

```
function connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
{
    // Erase the tenant connection, thus making Laravel get the default values all over again.
    DB::purge('business');
    // Make sure to use the database name we want to establish a connection.
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', $hostname);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $database);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $username);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $password);
    // Rearrange the connection data
    DB::reconnect('business');
    // Ping the database. This will throw an exception in case the database does not exists.
    Schema::connection('tenant')->getConnection()->reconnect();
}
```

Don't forget to tell the composer that the helper function can be used globally by adding those line into the composer.json file.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "files":[
        "database/utilities/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

You also want to have static and dynamic models that should be extended to define which database connections to use.

```
class StaticModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
class DynamicModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'business';
}
```

In the middleware set up the dynamic database connection according to the database name.

```
connect(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USERNAME'), getenv('DB_PASSWORD'), getenv('DB_SYMBOL') . $databasename);
```

Thus, you can use the model as normal but it has the dynamic database connections