# How to connect to multiple databases in laravel sail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have two database connections. One is postgresql (no problem) and the other is mysql.

I' ve been able to connect to the database and dump data from a file with this command:

```
cat cosmo.sql | docker exec -i edb9f60b1531 /usr/bin/mysql -u sail --password=password testing
```

But when I try to use eloquent it hangs up. This is a test I did:

```
use App\Models\Access;
Access::find(1);

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `access` where `access`.`id` = 1 limit 1).
```

This is from my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=pgsql
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=entropia_api
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_CONNECTION2=mysql
DB_HOST2=mysql
DB_PORT2=3306
DB_DATABASE2=testing
DB_USERNAME2=sail
DB_PASSWORD2=password
```

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DisposAcceso extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $table = 'access';
}
```

I haven't changed config/database.php, so I have the default connections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect multiple databases dynamically in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074804/connect-multiple-databases-dynamically-in-laravel)

Comment: can you run "php artisan migrate --database=testing" without any error?

Comment: Yes, I could migrate the database. But it's using pgsql connection.

Comment: your psql db name is "entropia_api", it is impossible to run above command on psql connection, unless there is another db on psql with name "testing", if it is, delete that one and run command again

Comment: can you show one migration file from each connection?

Comment: your migration should follow the pattern like this:
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('some-table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});

Comment: I don't need to run migrations on mysql, as I already have the data. I just need a working connection.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to multiple databases using Laravel Sail, follow these steps:

1. Add additional database configurations to the docker-compose.yml file. For example, to add a MySQL and a PostgreSQL database, add the following lines to the docker-compose.yml file:

   ```
   mysql:
   image: 'mysql:8.0'
   ports:
     - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
   environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
     MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
   volumes:
     - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
   networks:
     - sail
   container_name: sail-mysql

   pgsql:
   image: 'postgres:13'
   ports:
     - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
   environment:
     POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
     POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
   volumes:
     - 'sailpgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
   networks:
     - sail
   container_name: sail-pgsql
   ```
2. Add the additional database configurations to the .env file. For example:

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=mysql
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=my_database
   DB_USERNAME=my_username
   DB_PASSWORD=my_password

   DB_CONNECTION_PGSQL=pgsql
   DB_HOST_PGSQL=pgsql
   DB_PORT_PGSQL=5432
   DB_DATABASE_PGSQL=my_database_pgsql
   DB_USERNAME_PGSQL=my_username_pgsql
   DB_PASSWORD_PGSQL=my_password_pgsql
   ```
3. In your Laravel application, add the additional database connections to the config/database.php file. For example:

   ```
   'connections' => [

       'mysql' => [
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
           'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
           'prefix' => '',
           'prefix_indexes' => true,
           'strict' => true,
           'engine' => null,
       ],

       'pgsql' => [
           'driver' => 'pgsql',
           'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_PGSQL'),
           'host' => env('DB_HOST_PGSQL', '127.0.0.1'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT_PGSQL', '5432'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_PGSQL', 'forge'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_PGSQL', 'forge'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_PGSQL', ''),
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'prefix' => '',
           'prefix_indexes' => true,
           'schema' => 'public',
           'sslmode' => 'prefer',
       ],

   ],
   ```
4. To use the additional database connection, specify the connection name in your database queries. For example:

   ```
   $users = DB::connection('pgsql')->select('select * from users');
   ```